# Is using RTTI (or virtual functions that return a type tag) ever OK?

Tags: c++, rtti

Using RTTI (through the use of `typeid` and `dynamic_cast`) is pretty much universally considered to be poor programming practice.

Similarly, defining a type tag that all derivatives must return through a virtual function is also considered to be bad practice, e.g:

```
enum Type {
    DERIVED_1,
    DERIVED_2
};

class Base {
    virtual Type type() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    Type type() override {
        return DERIVED_1;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
    Type type() override {
        return DERIVED_2;
    }
};
```

However, sometimes I need to distinguish between different derived classes, like when I have a pointer to `Base` that may be either `Derived1` or `Derived2`:

```
Base *b = new Derived2();

// Approach 1:
if (typeid(*b) == typeid(Derived1)) {
    std::cout << "I have a Derived1.\n";
} else if (typeid(*b) == typeid(Derived2)) {
    std::cout << "I have a Derived2.\n";
}

// Approach 2:
if (b->type() == DERIVED_1) {
    std::cout << "I have a Derived1.\n";
} else if (b->type() == DERIVED_2) {
    std::cout << "I have a Derived2.\n";
}
```

People say that having a decision tree based on type is bad practice, but sometimes it's necessary!

Say I'm writing a compiler and need to decide whether a given expression can be assigned to:

```
/* ... */
Expr* parseAssignment(Expr *left) {
    // Is "left" a type of Expr that we can assign to?
    if (typeid(*left) == typeid(VariableExpr)) {
        // A VariableExpr can be assigned to, so continue pasrsing the expression

        /* ... */
    } else {
        // Any other type of Expr cannot be assigned to, so throw an error
        throw Error{"Invalid assignment target."};
    }
}
```

(Assume that Expr is the base class, and VariableExpr is a derivative among others)

Is there any other way to achieve behavior like this that is not considered bad practice? Or is RTTI/virtual functions and type tags OK in this situation?

Comment: There are good uses even for the dreaded and despised `goto`.

Comment: I am sorry, but why RTTI is considered poor? What else do you have? Good programming is about using the right thing in the right place, not just using or not using something because you are told to or not to.

Comment: The right question to usually isn’t “is this method good or bad”, but rather “is there a better way to accomplish my task?”  In this case, the better method is often a virtual method.

Comment: In this example case I think it might be better to change your parser to explicitly only allow variables on the left of assignment, but in general I agree with [R Sahu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54157070/27302).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not only OK to use `dynamic_cast` but it is essential in many contexts.

When I see code like that, I use the [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) as a guide.

If I have to revisit that `if-else` block or the `enum` when a new derived type is added to the system, I see that as a problem. If not, I don't think of it as a problem.

When you see cascading `if-else` blocks of code, it usually violates the [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) and should be avoided. The way to avoid that is to use a callback mechanism.

1. Let the base class have a function to register a callback function for derived types.
2. In the business logic of the base class, check whether a function has been registered for the derived type. If yes, call the function. If not, it is either to be ignored silently or an exception needs to be raised.